# Is there a way for RPubs to automatically re-run the markdown document every time the page is loaded?

Tags: r, markdown, rstudio, knitr

I currently have a markdown document which scrapes data from a website and outputs a table using that data. I published the HTML to RPubs using the knit function on Markdown. I'm wondering if there is a way for the table to be updated automatically on RPubs without having to go into R and knitting and publishing the document every day. The data from the website changes every day, so the table changes every day as well. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, RPubs just takes the static HTML file.

What you want is reactive markdown (using `shiny`) which you can also host for free. (Though unless you run your own server behind a firewall or pay it will be public)

Here is the tutorial: http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_shiny.html

In your case, since you don't actually want it to be reactive, just rerun, I don't think you are going to have to change much of your code.